# Which version of Eclipse is compatible with JDK 1.5?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working on an existing Java web project. I am getting lots of syntax errors in the files. It shows it needs JDK version 1.5. I have Eclipse Luna (4.4.1), which doesn't support JDK 1.5. How can I find out which version of Eclipse is compatible with JDK 1.5?

Comment: Eclipse Luna *is* compatible with 1.5, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to Preferences -> Java -> Installed JRE and add a new java VM which is Java 1.5.

Also, for your project, go to Project's properties -> java compiler. Check the checkbox to enable project specific setting and set the compliance level to java 1.5